# Using context to store variable globally React.js

Tags: reactjs, apollo

I want to store a global variable that's mutable and accessible in all files of my React.js project, including index.js where the ApolloClient is rendered. At first, I thought to create a class but I wasn't sure how to implement that and save the state of the variable across multiple pages. Upon doing research, I discovered the use of context, but I don't quite understand the documentation. Please advise what the best practice would be. Thank you.

Edit:

I attempted to import a global variable, but that isn't mutable. I also attempted making a class that extends React.Component, to access functionalities such as `useState()` but a class of that nature must return a component if I understand correctly. Upon reading into Context more, I'm starting to gain a little more understanding, but I still don't fully understand how to implement it.

I created a file AuthHandler:

```
import { createContext } from 'react';

export var AuthData = {
    id: createContext(0),
    auth: createContext("")
}
```

I want to mutate that data in a component function, and then access it in index.js. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I believe your question here is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) - you have done some research and come to the conclusion that a specific problem you have can be solved by storing a variable globally. But what is your *actual* problem? It might have a much simpler solution than that.

Comment: If you want a value to be available to multiple components without having to pass it as a prop a lot then context is the answer, but what is your actual problem?

Comment: Thank you for your responses, I updated my question with more details.

Comment: You write "but that isn't mutable": you probably declared that variable with `const`. If you used `let`, it would be mutable. 
You write "access it in index.js". **What do you want to access it for?** Do you want to grow tomatoes? Do you want to access it from the inside of an Apollo `setContext` link to access a current header that you need to send? Do you want to access it from a React component to display it as part of your UI? Each of those will have a different answer. You still haven't told us what you want to do, and why you want to do it.

Comment: @phry I thought imported variables were read only. If I have a global variable and try to change it in another file does it update in the original file (and reflected in other files in which it's called)? Or should I also import a function that mutates the variable? My goal is to set headers in the `ApolloClient` configuration, so I need to mutate the global variable in one component, and then access it to set a header in the index.js file.

Comment: It depends on how you import and export them, but you're right, you probably shouldn't depend on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use case here will be consumed by something outside of React (an Apollo Link), so Context does not make any sense here - Context would make a value available to children in the React tree, but your link is not a child in a React Tree.

Instead you can just export an object and modify that object (you probably cannot reassign it depending on how you import/export it, but you can always modify it).

```js
// index.js
export const globalData = {
  auth: null
}
```

```js
// anywhere else
import { globalData } from './index.js'

globalData.auth = "foo"
```

That said, you can only work with global data like this if you are not using SSR. If you are using SSR (e.g. in a Client Component in Next.js), you'd need to find another way of doing that.

In that case, you could use Apollo CLient's [`defaultContext`](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client-nextjs/issues/103#issuecomment-1790941212).

Answer (score -4):

if u want to store a variable globally u can use context api or redux-tool
kit
here i am giving a rough idea how u can achieve this using context API
first Create A folder usually context.. inside this create a file usually
name as DataProvider.jsx and do thing like this

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const DataContext = createContext(null);

const DataProvider = ({ children }) => {

const [Client, setClient] = useState([]);


return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={{
       Client, setClient
    }}
    >
        {children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
)
```

}

```
export default DataProvider;
```

next step u should wrap your app.js like this

```
import DataProvider from './context/DataProvider';

   function App() {
   return (
   <DataProvider>
     <Home />
   </DataProvider>
   );
}


export default App;
```

now u can setclient or u can use client data like below

assume u have a file name Client.jsx where u want to set the client data

```
const { setCleint} = useContext(DataContext)
```

set the Client data to setClient just as normal state
now in similar way u can render the client list anywhere like this

```
const { Cleint} = useContext(DataContext);
```